# How to label windows drive for ebs volume mounted on Windows EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am trying to setup a static html page to be hosted on EBS volume that is mounted on Windows EC2 (I could do this in Linux but need to do on Windows now). I also need to configure IIS to make this as default location. i.e. can't host my pages on ephemeral storage (and hence this EBS). But I am struggling on how to (1) place my static files on this EBS and (2) configure IIS to have this as default location. I am assuming if i solve (1), then part (2) also gets solved.

I have launched a Windows EC2 instance, mounted a 1GB EBS volume and am able to RDP and see the 1GB volume in the Disk Management screen (shows up as Disk1, while C-drive shows up as Disk0). I need to host a simple static html page on the EBS volume (and not on temporary storage).

I am lost on how to place my html files on this Disk1 (and once i do this i can change the default website settings in IIS to look for this new drive/folder).

This link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-volumes.html talks about getting volume ID's but i am not sure what I can do even i get the vol ID. (I am a novice and not sure how to configure IIS to look, by default, at folder on this volume ID)

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I could right click on the sloped stripes area in the Disk Management window and it gives option to lable the volume. I had clicked earlier on the box just left to this one and it wasn't giving this option.